# Implement DisplayManager in a service

Tags: android, service

I have created an AIDL IPC service meant to be called by a client application.

ipc_server

```
package com.zzzz.ipc_server

import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService

import com.zzzz.ipc_library.IIPCInterface

class IPCServiceImpl : IIPCInterface.Stub()
{
    override fun returnValues(): Int
    {
        val numberValues = 1

        val dm = getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager

        return numberValues
    }
}
```

How can I use DisplayManager and its functions inside the service implementation? The line `val dm = getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager` already gives an error when I tried to use the code and I cannot proceed further.

```
Type mismatch
Required: Context
Found: String

Create abstract function getSystemService
```